# Flexbox centering box issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

currently I am having trouble with two things on my site. The first one is that my three icons keep stretching across the whole browser. When it hits a certain point I don't want the icons to continue to have so much space between them. I'm assuming I'd have to make some kind of box to keep them in but I feel like there's a better way with flexbox to do this. I know this is a bit confusing so if you need me to explain more let me know. The second issue I'm having is that my "do you want to" lists are sticking to the left side of the browser instead of flexing into the center as I move the browser. If anyone can help me figure this centering issue out it would really help a lot! Thank you!

```css
body{
 background-image: url(footer_lodyas.png);
 }


ml, body {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

.center{
 
 margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 display: block;
 
}

/***************flexbox icons************/
.container {
    display: flex;
 background-color: #1DA0A3;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
  
  .box{
    flex: 1 0 200px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    margin:1em;
 
  }
  
  .box img{
    align-self: center;
    width: 180px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
  
  .box .buy{
    align-self: center;
    margin-top: auto;
  }


.flexwords{
 align-self: center;
 margin-top: auto;
}

#contacticon{
  width:100px;
 }


/****************horizontal line*************/
.hr1{
 
 border: none;  
    border-bottom: 1px solid #293839;  
 margin-left:25%;
   width: 50%;               
  color:#485A5F;
   height: 2px;
 }
 
/***************Do you want to section*************/ 
.wrap{
 display:flex;
 
}

main{
 flex:1;
 display:flex;
 justify-content: center;
}

aside, article{

padding:2em; 
}

aside{
 flex:0 auto;
}

article{
 flex:0 auto;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  main {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">

<title>portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>


 
 
 
 


<div class="container">
    
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-multimedia/1024/iMac-icon.png" alt="" />
      <h2 class="flexwords">My Work</h2>
      
    </div>
    
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-multimedia/1024/iMac-icon.png" alt="" />
      <h2 class="flexwords">My Education</h2>
    </div>
        
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-multimedia/1024/iMac-icon.png" id="contacticon" alt="" />
      <h2 class="flexwords">Contact Me</h2>
      
    </div>
      
       
<br>

<hr class="hr1">


<div class="wrap">
<main>
<aside>
 <h1>Do You Want to...</h1>
    <ul>
  <li>Rebrand myself online</li>
  <li>Take my current website and make it modern</li>
  <li>Find a way to make information more accessible for customers</li>
  <li> Improve customer service</li>
  <li> Reach a wider range of people</li>
</ul>
</aside>
<article>
<h1>Do You Want to...</h1>

<ul>
  <li>Create forms and documents that customers can fill out online</li>
  <li>Start an email list for recurring customers</li>
  <li>Show relatability with my audience</li>
  <li> Have 24/7 online exposure</li>
  <li>Create a map or a way for customers to find my location</li>
</ul>
</article>

</main>
</div>
```

Comment: add `width: 100%;` to `.wrap`. re: your icons, you need to explain more how you expect them to behave as you make the viewport smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the icons container a max width, and center it using auto margin

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #1DA0A3;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    max-width: 800px;            /*  added  */
    margin: 0 auto;              /*  added  */
}
```

Sample

```css
body {
  background-image: url(footer_lodyas.png);
}
ml,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}
/***************flexbox icons************/

.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #1DA0A3;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box {
  flex: 1 0 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  margin: 1em;
  max-width: 300px;
}
.box img {
  align-self: center;
  width: 180px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.box .buy {
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: auto;
}
.flexwords {
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: auto;
}
#contacticon {
  width: 100px;
}
/****************horizontal line*************/

.hr1 {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #293839;
  margin-left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  color: #485A5F;
  height: 2px;
}
/***************Do you want to section*************/

.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
aside,
article {
  padding: 2em;
}
aside {
  flex: 0 auto;
}
article {
  flex: 0 auto;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  main {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-multimedia/1024/iMac-icon.png" alt="" />
      <h2 class="flexwords">My Work</h2>

    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-multimedia/1024/iMac-icon.png" alt="" />
      <h2 class="flexwords">My Education</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-multimedia/1024/iMac-icon.png" id="contacticon" alt="" />
      <h2 class="flexwords">Contact Me</h2>

    </div>


    <br>

    <hr class="hr1">


    <div class="wrap">
      <main>
        <aside>
          <h1>Do You Want to...</h1>
          <ul>
            <li>Rebrand myself online</li>
            <li>Take my current website and make it modern</li>
            <li>Find a way to make information more accessible for customers</li>
            <li>Improve customer service</li>
            <li>Reach a wider range of people</li>
          </ul>
        </aside>
        <article>
          <h1>Do You Want to...</h1>

          <ul>
            <li>Create forms and documents that customers can fill out online</li>
            <li>Start an email list for recurring customers</li>
            <li>Show relatability with my audience</li>
            <li>Have 24/7 online exposure</li>
            <li>Create a map or a way for customers to find my location</li>
          </ul>
        </article>

      </main>
    </div>
```

---

Or give the icons container `justify-content: center` to center them, and each box a max width

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #1DA0A3;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;          /*  added  */
}
.box {
  flex: 1 0 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  margin: 1em;
  max-width: 300px;                 /*  added  */
}
```

Sample

```css
body {
  background-image: url(footer_lodyas.png);
}
ml,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}
/***************flexbox icons************/

.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #1DA0A3;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box {
  flex: 1 0 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  margin: 1em;
  max-width: 300px;
}
.box img {
  align-self: center;
  width: 180px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.box .buy {
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: auto;
}
.flexwords {
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: auto;
}
#contacticon {
  width: 100px;
}
/****************horizontal line*************/

.hr1 {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #293839;
  margin-left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  color: #485A5F;
  height: 2px;
}
/***************Do you want to section*************/

.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
aside,
article {
  padding: 2em;
}
aside {
  flex: 0 auto;
}
article {
  flex: 0 auto;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  main {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-multimedia/1024/iMac-icon.png" alt="" />
      <h2 class="flexwords">My Work</h2>

    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-multimedia/1024/iMac-icon.png" alt="" />
      <h2 class="flexwords">My Education</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-multimedia/1024/iMac-icon.png" id="contacticon" alt="" />
      <h2 class="flexwords">Contact Me</h2>

    </div>


    <br>

    <hr class="hr1">


    <div class="wrap">
      <main>
        <aside>
          <h1>Do You Want to...</h1>
          <ul>
            <li>Rebrand myself online</li>
            <li>Take my current website and make it modern</li>
            <li>Find a way to make information more accessible for customers</li>
            <li>Improve customer service</li>
            <li>Reach a wider range of people</li>
          </ul>
        </aside>
        <article>
          <h1>Do You Want to...</h1>

          <ul>
            <li>Create forms and documents that customers can fill out online</li>
            <li>Start an email list for recurring customers</li>
            <li>Show relatability with my audience</li>
            <li>Have 24/7 online exposure</li>
            <li>Create a map or a way for customers to find my location</li>
          </ul>
        </article>

      </main>
    </div>
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much for helping me I truly appreciate it! @LGSon

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to fixing this would be to wrap them in another container and give that container a maximum width.

To fix your second problem give .container "justify-content: center;".

Answer (score 0):

To fix the centering issue, add this to your stylesheet. The style type of the list had to be removed to make it perfectly centered.

```
@media (max-width: 420px) {
    .wrap {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .wrap ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
}
```